# Getting error while deploying cloud formation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am getting below error when deploying an EC2. I am importing security group value from already deployed stack.

"The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet"

my EC2 code as below:

```
Parameters:
     AvailabilityZones:
      Type: CommaDelimitedList
      Default: "ap-south-1a, ap-south-1b, ap-south-1c"

     ImageID:
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
      Description: select updated AMI Ids
      Default: /aws/service/ami-windows-latest/EC2LaunchV2-Windows_Server-2016-English-Core-Base

Resources:
     EC2:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
      Properties:
           ImageId: !Ref ImageID
           InstanceType: t2.micro
           SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
           AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !Ref AvailabilityZones]
           SecurityGroupIds:
                - !ImportValue SecurityGroup-RDP

     MyVPC:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
      Properties:
           CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/20
           Tags:
                - Key: Name
                  Value: Demo-VPC      


     SubnetA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
           VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
           CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/22
           AvailabilityZone: !Select [0,!Ref AvailabilityZones] 
           Tags:
                - Value: Name
                  Key: Subnet-A
```

below is the output code of already deployed stack. This code ran successfully and then getting error for above stack

```
Resources:
    SecurityGroup:
     Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
     Properties:
          GroupDescription: SG for Windows
          GroupName: SG for Windows
          SecurityGroupIngress:
               - IpProtocol: tcp
                 FromPort: 3389
                 ToPort: 3389
                 CidrIp: 157.33.245.134/32
          Tags:
               - Value: Name
                 Key: SG for Windoes EC2

Outputs:
   SecurityGroupRDP:
    Description: The RDP Security Group 
    Value: !Ref SecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: SecurityGroup-RDP
```

Please help to understand what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should return group id:

```
Value: !GetAtt SecurityGroup.GroupId
```